# Iterate through first n elements of array - if that many exist

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a more elegant, 'Ruby-ists' way to do the following. Is there any cleaner way to do this?

```
i=0
array.each do |x|
    break if x.empty?
    puts x
    i+=1
    break if i>4
end
```

Comment: Your code does not do anything in the first place. It is invalid.

Comment: Fixed, apologies I copied it in wrong

Comment: Suppose `array = [[1],[],[2],[3],[4],[5]]`, Your code prints `1` and then breaks.  That is consistent with how David and I interpreted the question.  @Neil's code using `compact` and `reject` print `1,2,3` and `1,2,3,4`, respectively, yet you accepted his answer.  Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest [Array#first](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-first) as follows:

```
array.first(4).each do |x|
  puts x
end
```

If you only want to accept the first so many non-nil entries, then filter them out using [Array#compact](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact):

```
array.compact.first(4).each do |x|
  puts x
end
```

If you are concerned about empty values then you could still chain the filters using [Array#reject](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject):

```
array.reject(&:empty?).first(4).each do |x|
  puts x
end
```

Comment: None of these examples preserve the original behavior of the code, which is to break after seeing the first empty element, ignoring all elements after it.

Comment: Good point. Although I wonder if `x.empty?` is spurious in OP's code (an attempt to not go beyond end of array, despite `.each` already doing the right thing there). In which case the first suggestion would be a match

Comment: I believe the first one can be simplified to `puts array[0,4]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Yes, although the `puts` is standing in for whatever processing OP really wants to do with `x`

Answer (score 4):

I saw that you were calling `#empty?` on the elements in your array and quitting when you see the first empty element.  If you want to preserve that behavior, you could do:

```
array.first(4).each do |x|
  break if x.empty?
  puts x
end
```

A fancier way would be:

```
array.take_while { |i| !i.empty? }.first(4).each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

I am not sure how many elements you want to print; please note that my examples will print at most 4 elements, whereas your code was printing up to 5.

Comment: Note both of these work when `array.size < 4`. Consider using `i.any?` rather than `!i.empty?`. Also, `i` is perhaps not a good name for the block variable.

Comment: Are you not missing `each` statements on both of those examples?

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
def printem(a,n)
  puts a[0, [a.index(&:empty?) || n, n].min]
end

printem [[], [2],[3],[4],[5],[6]], 4
  # <prints nothing>
printem [[1],[2], [],[4],[5],[6]], 4
  # 1
  # 2
printem [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]], 4
  # 1
  # 2
  # 3
  # 4
printem [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]], 7
  # 1
  # 2
  # 3
  # 4
  # 5
  # 6
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `printem [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[]], 4` would fail the specification.  You would end up printing 6 elements.

Comment: Thanks for the catch,  @DavidGrayson. I believe it's OK now, but have a look.